# scheme - Evaluate true or false list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have a true/false list (like this (#f #f #f #f #f #t)) and I want to loop through it, making an if statement and making appends.

But my map/if iterator does not work as I expected

I`m trying this:

```
(map (if (false? lst) "do this" "do that" ) lst)
```

In pseudo code I would have something like this

```
for each value in lst
  if value
    "do that"
  else
    "do this"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `map` receives as parameters a list and a *function* that operates on each element. Try this:

```
(map (lambda (e)
       (if (false? e)
           "do this"
           "do that"))
     lst)
```

For example, if we define `lst` as `'(#f #f #f #f #f #t)` the result is:

```
'("do this" "do this" "do this" "do this" "do this" "do that")
```